# query with sql max function

Tags: mysql, sql

[table view with 4 records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N04Gx.png)

Would the following query work if I wanted to select the 2nd and 3rd records?

```
select driver_name, driver_city, driver_email, max(due_date), max(completion_date)
from TableX
group by driver_name,driver_city,driver_email
```

Comment: What does 2nd and 3rd mean? What is the order?

Comment: Well, execute it and you'll have your answer

Comment: @Cid the problem is it works but i dont have an entry like the 3rd record in my database,unsure how it will behave if that entry were to be there.

Comment: @HoneyBadger They are in the attached image.

Comment: Give some sample data and your expected output.

Comment: @mkRabbani sample data image has been attached.

Comment: There is no obvious sorting in the image. Please add sample data as (formatted) text in your question.

Comment: Please read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: 'wanted to select the 2nd and 3rd records' - I think you want the rows with the max completed_date per driver_name,driver_city,driver_email ? - This is quite different to asking for 2nd and 3rd rows

Comment: @P.Salmon well yes-true.How do i go about that?

Comment: mysql 8 supports *Windowed Aggregates*, in your case `row_number`

Comment: @questioner07 the answer from mkRabbani looks correct.

Comment: @P.Salmon Tried it but unfortunately did not work

Comment: @questioner07 It does work if the completed date is in mysql date format - if it's not then you need to convert it - this would apply to any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your date values are not in well formatted, you need to first convert your values into DATE and then apply other logic. Please check my updated script now-

**Issues:**

1. You value in completion_date column is string. as a result, MAX was returning the value considering STRING, not DATE.
2. You have no YEAR value in the completion_date column. As a result, I just added '2020' to the value so that DATE value generated properly. At the end, the added year has no impact on the output. And this is considering all DTAEs are from the single (any) YEAR only.
3. But if you have YEAR value in some other column, avoid adding static '2020' and use the value from that column

Check [DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=faeb3c51e619173fbe8c4f3d59791e63)

```
    SELECT A.*
FROM TableX A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT driver_email, 
    MAX(STR_TO_DATE(
        CONCAT(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(REPLACE(completion_date,'rd ','-'),
            'st ',
            '-'
        ),
        'th ',
        '-'
    ),'-2020') ,'%d-%b-%Y')) completion_date
    FROM TableX 
    GROUP BY driver_email
) B ON A.driver_email = B.driver_email
AND STR_TO_DATE(
        CONCAT(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(REPLACE(A.completion_date,'rd ','-'),
            'st ',
            '-'
        ),
        'th ',
        '-'
    ),'-2020') ,'%d-%b-%Y') = B.completion_date
```

Comment: @questioner07 Maybe, if you provide useful feedback on why it gives you no luck, you'll get an answer that will.

Comment: @questioner07 please check my updated answer with explanation why first script was not working.

Answer (score 0):

It will return 2nd and 4th records as result. Because the 3rd record has empty value in the DueDate column

Comment: how do i tweak the query to get the 2nd and the 3rd.basically in want the records only with the max completion date.